# Magento2 - ship button is missing!

Tags: magento2, shipping, frontend, shipment-tracking

In my installation, the ship button is actually missing.

What is wrong?

I know orders must be invoiced and an email sent.I've done both.

Am I missing some other requisites?

Does cron not being set up have anything to do with this?

[image: tutorial has ship button]
[image: Mine has no ship button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an order programmatically, the shipping method string needs to have an underscore character `_` followed by non-empty charcters as well.

`_shipping` works
`free_shipping` works

`free_` does NOT work.

What the heck, magento........ -_-

I've traced this down to some line where explode is used, and then the results are assigned to multiple variables in a single line. This results in requiring both elements to exist as a result of the explosion. So if there is no underscore character, there will no tbe two pieces, which means one of the variables being assigned the result of the explosion will not exist, and you will run into a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

> First, **Sending Tracking Information** button come only when
>   Shipment is created. It is not coming on shipment create page. 2nd
>   Screenshot shows  that you are on **Shipment creation** Page.

As per as your screenshot,you are trying to create  ***`New shipment`*** .I **don't see  any ordered items available for shipment**.I guess that some extension/Customization is overriding your shipment functionally.

Comment: i had no modules or customizations.
It was out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Click the **Submit Shipment** button at the bottom of the page:

[image: Shipment Creation]

The open this shipment and you can see the **Send Tracking Information** button at the top of the page:

[image: Created shipment]

Comment: it wasn't showing up at the bottom of the page either

Answer (score 0):

It happens in case your product does not have any weight.
When I product does not have any weight assigned it becomes a virtual product and virtual products cannot be shipped.